selección de variables usando el nombre de las etiquetas en Shiny
Tengo un archivo de datos en el cual he asignado etiquetas a los nombres de las variables. Como hago para que al aplicar la función inputSelect en Shiny, la opción "choices" me permita ver y seleccionar usando el nombre de las etiquetas y no el nombre original de las variables?
